# Trouble with php upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on php upload and i have an issue on how to automatically rename a file it does exist already in file folder. Could you give me any road or tips about it? thanks

here is my full code - the code is for testing purpose only

```
$destination = 'C:/upload_test/';
$max=75200;
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
$fileTaille= $_FILES['image']['size'];
if ($fileTaille==true) {
if ($fileTaille > $max) {
    echo "Your file is too large, select a file smaller than". " ".$fileTaille;
    exit(include 'form.php');
   }
 }
   else {
    echo "No file selected";
    exit(include 'form.php');
   }
}

$file_type=getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

 if ($file_type==true) {
   echo "File is an image - " .$file_type["mime"]." ";
 }
  else{
    echo "Could not get file type";
  }
$fileType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);

 if (!in_array($fileType, $allowed)) {
   echo "File type not accepted, Only JPEG file allowed";
   exit(include 'form.php');
 }

$sanitize_file = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9\.\_-]/i", " ", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

$fileName = $recipient . basename($recipient);
 if (file_exists($fileName)) {
   echo "File already exist";
   exit(include 'form.php');
 }

}

if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $recipient . $sanitize_file); 

  if ($result == true) {
  echo "file moved "." ";
  }else
    {
    echo "Could not move filed";
    }

  $permission = chmod($$recipient . $sanitize_file, 0644);
  if ($permission==false) {
    echo "No permission to the file";
  }
   else
   {
    echo "permission given";
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you storing on a database that this file has been uploaded

Comment: @No i am storing the upload file in a databse..i am storing the file images in my folder located on my C:DRIVE...

Comment: Yes, so instead of worrying about filenames for the images on disk, just use the auto increment fields number as the filename i.e. `table.id` then they are always bound to be unique. Et voila problem solved. Plus they are easy to find again